# restore db from .bak file that contains multi backup

Tags: sql-server, restore

I backup my database and I Mistakenly saved it without a name.

what happened is that instead of replace the last file it add to it the last backup.

now I have a .bak file that has 74 backups
[image]

I want to restore the db in position 74 with query ,since restore from the wizrad always return "db in use"

I tried

```
alter database <dbname>
set single_user with rollback immediate
```

with no luck,so my only option is throw query window

any idea how to restore the one db from the file in position 74?

Thanks for any help

Baaroz

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not SQL server support. Try the DBA site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter how many backups are there. You would have the same error message if there was only one backup in the backup set.

I would either restore the backup 74 under different database name (put its name in "To database" textbox), or would rename current database to some other name, e.g. spetztest_OLD and restore the backup under original name. Then you can make sure you don't need the old one and drop it.

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
USE [MASTER]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [spetztest] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [spetztest] FROM  DISK = N'c:\sdk.bak' WITH FILE = 74,  REPLACE,  STATS = 1
GO
```

Make sure that your session that you are using to do the restore is not using the database you want to restore.